# Symmetric Polynomials in Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, lie-groups, lie-algebras, symmetric-polynomials

I'm interested in symmetric polynomials. Could you name some nice examples in Differential Geometry where they are clearly useful?

I would also be interested in algebraic examples if connected with Lie Algebras and Lie Groups.

Comment: Look up Chern-Weil theory.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have some link or reference to start with?